# pandas dataframe: return column that is a compression of other columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with a lot of columns, an arbitrary number of which the column names fit a specific string pattern. I want to create a new column that is set to 'r' if any of those other columns has an 'r' in it. I can do something like this:

```
for col in df.columns:
    if 'abc' in col:
        for i in df.index:
            if df.ix[i, col] == 'r':
                df.ix[i, 'newcol'] = 'r'
```

However this is a bit ugly and slow. Is there a faster way to do this?

Edit: including a sample of what my source data could look like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'abc1':['r','r','n','n'], 'abc2':['r','n','n','r'], 'xyz1':['r','n','n','n'], 'xyz2':['n','n','r','n']})
```

The output I need (in 'newcol') is:

```
  abc1 abc2 xyz1 xyz2 newcol
0    r    r    r    n      r
1    r    n    n    n      r
2    n    n    n    r    nan
3    n    r    n    n      r
```

(nan could be replaced by pretty much anything as long as it's not 'r'). 
Alternatively newcol could contain `True, True, False, True` which would also work fine for my purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I'd probably do it as follows (an example dataframe the hopefully captures your situation well enough):

```
>>> df

   A  B abc1 abc2 abc3 abc4
0  1  4    x    r    a    d
1  1  3    y    d    b    e
2  2  4    z    e    c    r
3  3  5    r    g    d    f
4  4  8    z    z    z    z
```

Get the columns of interest:

```
>>> cols = [x for x in df.columns if 'abc' in x]
>>> cols
['abc1', 'abc2', 'abc3', 'abc4']

>>> df['newcol'] = (df[cols] == 'r').any(axis=1).map({True:'r',False:'np.nan'})
>>> df

  A  B abc1 abc2 abc3 abc4  newcol
0  1  4    x    r    a    d       r
1  1  3    y    d    b    e  np.nan
2  2  4    z    e    c    r       r
3  3  5    r    g    d    f       r
4  4  8    z    z    z    z  np.nan
```

This should be pretty fast; I think even the use of map here will be a Cythonized call. If a boleen vector is sufficient for the newcol, you could just simplify it to the following:

```
>>> df['newcol'] = (df[cols] == 'r').any(axis=1)
>>> df

   A  B abc1 abc2 abc3 abc4 newcol
0  1  4    x    r    a    d   True
1  1  3    y    d    b    e  False
2  2  4    z    e    c    r   True
3  3  5    r    g    d    f   True
4  4  8    z    z    z    z  False
```

Now, if  you need to check if the strings contain 'r' instead of equalling 'r', you could do as follows:

```
>>> df

  A  B abc1  abc2 abc3 abc4
0  1  4    x  root    a    d
1  1  3    y     d    b    e
2  2  4    z     e    c  bar
3  3  5    r     g    d    f
4  4  8    z     z    z    z

>>> cols = [x for x in df.columns if 'abc' in x]
>>> df['newcol'] = df[cols].apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('r'),axis=0).any(axis=1)
>>> df['newcol'] = df['newcol'].map({True:'r',False:'np.nan'}) 
>>> df

   A  B abc1  abc2 abc3 abc4  newcol
0  1  4    x  root    a    d       r
1  1  3    y     d    b    e  np.nan
2  2  4    z     e    c  bar       r
3  3  5    r     g    d    f       r
4  4  8    z     z    z    z  np.nan
```

This should still be pretty fast because it uses `pandas`' vectorized string methods for each of the columns (the apply is across the columns, not an iteration over the rows).

Comment: This was perfect - thank you for providing so many options. I decided to go with the 2nd (boolean vector) option for its simplicity. I'd somehow missed any(), which is very useful.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [apply](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.13.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) with a custom function over *axis=1*:

```
get_val_for_row = lambda items: 'r' if (items == 'r').any() else None

df['newcol'] = df.apply(get_val_for_row, axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks, I like this but it doesn't directly work with only a subset of all columns.

Comment: @fantabolous Actually, it does. Just specify the columns when you apply the function, like this: `df[['col1', 'col2']].apply(...)`